# Проблема с выдвижением меню(в codepen работает, в проекте нет )

Tags: html, jquery, css3

Подскажите почему не срабатывает нажатие на меню

```js
$('.menu_btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.menu_adapt').toggleClass('menu_active');
});
```

```css
.menu a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.menu_adapt {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #000;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(300px);
}

.menu_active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="menu_btn">MENU</a>
  <div class="menu_adapt">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Где что не отрабатывает?

Comment: @Qwertiy, видимо он имел ввиду тег `a` :)

Comment: @meine, так вроде ж работает...

Comment: @Qwertiy, угу).

Comment: в том то и дело, что в codepen все работает, а в проекте нет

Comment: @АлександрПогребняк, и откуда мы узнаем из-за чего не работает?)

Comment: Значит дело в проекте, показывайте код.